# Extracting hrefs from a list in R with some missing values

Tags: html, r, list, rvest, purrr

I am keen to extract the source and demo urls for a set of jekyll themes into a data.frame

```
library(rvest)

info <- read_html("https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/wiki/themes")

data <- info %>%
 html_nodes(" #wiki-body li")

data
{xml_nodeset (115)}


[11] <li>Typewriter - (<a href="https://github.com/alixedi/typewriter">source</a>, <a href="http://alixedi.github.io/typewriter">demo</a>)</li>
[12] <li>block-log - (<a href="https://github.com/anandubajith/block-log">source</a>), <a href="https://anandu.net/demo/block-log/">demo</a>)</li>
[13] <li>Otter Pop - (<a href="https://github.com/tybenz/otter-pop">source</a>)</li>
```

So I want a data.frame(df) with 3 columns e.g

```
name        source                                       demo
Typewriter   https://github.com/alixedi/typewriter         http://alixedi.github.io/typewriter
```

I am able to extract all  hrefs as a vector but, as you can see, from [13] there is no demo for some of the sites so I then encounter difficulties

Is there a simple way I can create df from data? Possibly using the purrr library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your `purrr`-ish answer:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

info <- read_html("https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/wiki/themes")

themes <- html_nodes(info, xpath=".//div[@class='markdown-body']/*/li")

zero_to_na <- function(x) { ifelse(length(x)==0, NA, x) }

df <- data_frame(name=gsub(" [- ]*\\(.*$", "", html_text(themes)),
                 source=map_chr(themes, ~html_attr(html_nodes(., xpath=".//a[contains(., 'source')]"), "href")),
                 demo=map_chr(themes, ~zero_to_na(html_attr(html_nodes(., xpath=".//a[contains(., 'demo')]"), "href"))))

glimpse(df)
## Observations: 115
## Variables: 3
## $ name   <chr> "Jalpc", "Pixyll", "Jekyll Metro", "Midnight", "Leap Day", "F...
## $ source <chr> "https://github.com/Jack614/jalpc_jekyll_theme", "https://git...
## $ demo   <chr> "http://www.jack003.com", "http://pixyll.com/", "http://blog-...
```

alternately:

```
map_df(themes, function(x) {
  data_frame(name=gsub(" [- ]*\\(.*$", "", html_text(x)),
             source=html_attr(html_nodes(x, xpath=".//a[contains(., 'source')]"), "href"),
             demo=zero_to_na(html_attr(html_nodes(x, xpath=".//a[contains(., 'demo')]"), "href")))
})
```

`gsub`/`sub`/etc whatever part of the "name" you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for inc purrr functions. It's quite the learning curve

Answer (score 4):

```
data_out <- c()
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  row <- data.frame(html_text(data[i]), as.character(html_children(data[[i]]))[1], as.character(html_children(data[[i]]))[2])
  data_out <- rbind(data_out, row)
}
names(data_out) <- c("name", "source", "demo")
data_out$name <- gsub(" - [(]source, demo[)]", "", data_out$name)
data_out$source <- gsub("<a href=\"|\">source</a>", "", data_out$source)
data_out$demo <- gsub("<a href=\"|\">demo</a>", "", data_out$demo)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing yet another alternative

Answer (score 2):

You can collect those with demo data and those without demo data separately using xpath to separate the two groups:

```
withDemo <- info %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//li[contains(., 'source') and contains(., 'demo')]")

withoutDemo <- info %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//li[contains(., 'source') and not(contains(.,'demo'))]")
```

Then, create the dataframe for the collection with source and demo links:

```
sourceNdemo <- withDemo %>%
    html_children() %>%              # get all children
    html_attr("href") %>%            # get the href attributes
    matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)   # 2 pieces of data for each row

sourceNdemo <- setNames(
    data.frame(html_text(withDemo), sourceNdemo),  # html_text to get "name" column
    c("name", "source", "demo"))
```

Then, create the data frame for the ones with only source data

```
source <- withoutDemo %>% 
    html_children() %>%
    html_attr("href")

# set demo = NA for easy rbind-ing
source <- data.frame(name = html_text(withoutDemo), source = source, demo = NA)
```

`rbind` the two dataframes

```
allInfo <- rbind(sourceNdemo, source)
```

The "name" column now contains entries like "Jalpc - (source, demo)" and ""Bitwiser-Material (source, demo)".  You can get rid of the extra "(source, demo)" bits using gsub:

```
allInfo$name <- sub("\\s(-\\s)?\\(.+$", "", allInfo$name, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: This appeared fastest approach and might be better alternative for larger inputs